# Database format for android and iOS

Tags: android, xml, database, ios

I'm currently developing an application for android which will require a database. The database will be updatable from the web, and I'm thinking in porting it to iOS in the future, but I would like to use the same database (which will be very large). My idea is to have an online database in XML format, then the android app would connect to it, download the XML file and create the database locally (I was thinking in using db4o), then in the future the iOS application could do the same, download the XML file and create a new local database.

Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite is available on both platforms, and SQLite files are probably more compact than equivalent XML. That could be an important consideration if, as you say, your database is very large.

Comment: Caleb is absolutely right but is it really that important to use the same db engine on Android and iOS since the two platforms will never share code and it sounds like they will never share db files since all your data is transferred via XML?

However I still recommend Sqlite because it is such a great embedded db.

Comment: Would it be easy to update the database online? Like getting a dump from my server and load it on the device?

Answer (score 0):

would it not be better to build a simple api that returns json that both android and iOS can access to update/write to a mysql or similar database?

Comment: I don't want an online database, the database will always be local on both devices. I just need an online database for update the local one.

Comment: Misread your post, I took the "database will be updateable from the web to me that there'd be some sort of dashboard to update the db which the apps would pull from. In that case SQLite is the way to go.